Converting image to FEN programmatically
I'm wanting to create a little screenshot tool that takes a screenshot and outputs an FEN to the clipboard. I was hoping to use chessvision.ai, but it does not seem to have an API that allows me to use it programmatically. What alternatives might suit my needs (accurate conversion from image to FEN, and accessible programmatically i.e. from the command line to be chained with a screenshot tool).
Note, I've looked at the following two threads:
How can I convert screenshot capture into FEN to analyse on Windows 10+?
How can I scan a chessboard and obtain its FEN?
Neither answers my particular question, which is the need to be able to access the image->FEN conversion tool programmatically.

be aware that a screenshot might not have all information. It can be impossible to tell if castling is still allowed or if en passant is possible

Indeed. I was hoping that the algorithm would be able to predict those features of a position, but obviously that would be less than perfect. Still though, fixing those minor details about a position is a vast improvement from having to set up every position you are reading in a book by hand.

There is a open-source project called Chess Vision that is self-hostable

Is your diagram chess font always the same or does it vary? Obviously, the latter would be horrible even for a neural net.

@HaukeReddmann It should be able to vary. As Nicolas points out, ChessVision can handle this, but I haven't figured out how to use it programmatically.

Chessvision.ai actually has an API that it uses to predict the FEN of a position based on an image. If you want to experiment with it, you can see the requests the extension makes after scanning a position in the extension's background console.
In short, it seems that Chessvision.ai makes a POST request to http://app.chessvision.ai/predict in order to extract the FEN of a chess position, supplying the board orientation, a cropped field which is true if the image was cropped manually and false otherwise, the color of the player that has the move (based on this toggle), the image data (base64 encoded) and a flag to predict the player's turn. For example:
{
    board_orientation: "predict"
    cropped: false
    current_player: "white"
    image: "data:image/jpeg;base64,..."
    predict_turn: true
}

If the request is successful, the API returns a JSON object containing the board orientation, the predicted FEN and the predicted turn (can be null). For example:
{
    board_orientation: "default"
    result: "<fen!>"
    success: true
    turn: "white"
}

Note that since this API is not publicly documented, it might change at any time.
